# Android Bitmap.compress rotates image, I need to return it to normal orientation before writing to file

Tags: android, kotlin, android-camera, android-bitmap, android-file

I am using Bitmap.compress to write to file which results in image orientation being wrong. I tried using EXIF and a lot of different approaches but it doesn't seem to be working as I have to write it to file and I lose the orientation when I do. This happens when I take a picture from the camera/ (or select picture taken from the gallery) and its height > width. The image goes from being upright to -90 degrees. The problem is that I cannot do anything to the compression, so the file gets saved with wrong orientation. I somehow need to save correctly oriented image to the tempFile

Preferably something that works on API 21+

```
   @Throws(IOException::class)
    fun getCorrectlyOrientedImage( photoUri: Uri?): Bitmap? {
        var `is` = context.contentResolver.openInputStream(photoUri!!)
        val dbo = BitmapFactory.Options()
        dbo.inJustDecodeBounds = true
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(`is`, null, dbo)
        `is`!!.close()
        val rotatedWidth: Int
        val rotatedHeight: Int
        val orientation = getOrientation(context, photoUri)
        if (orientation == 90 || orientation == 270) {
            rotatedWidth = dbo.outHeight
            rotatedHeight = dbo.outWidth
        } else {
            rotatedWidth = dbo.outWidth
            rotatedHeight = dbo.outHeight
        }
        var srcBitmap: Bitmap?
        `is` = context.contentResolver.openInputStream(photoUri)
        if (rotatedWidth > MAX_IMAGE_DIMENSION || rotatedHeight > MAX_IMAGE_DIMENSION) {
            val widthRatio = rotatedWidth.toFloat() / MAX_IMAGE_DIMENSION.toFloat()
            val heightRatio = rotatedHeight.toFloat() / MAX_IMAGE_DIMENSION.toFloat()
            val maxRatio = max(widthRatio, heightRatio)

            // Create the bitmap from file
            val options = BitmapFactory.Options()
            options.inSampleSize = maxRatio.toInt()
            srcBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(`is`, null, options)
        } else {
            srcBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(`is`)
        }
        `is`!!.close()

        /*
     * if the orientation is not 0 (or -1, which means we don't know), we
     * have to do a rotation.
     */if (orientation > 0) {
            val matrix = Matrix()
            matrix.postRotate(orientation.toFloat())
            srcBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                srcBitmap!!, 0, 0, srcBitmap.width,
                srcBitmap.height, matrix, true
            )
        }
        return srcBitmap
    }

    private fun getOrientation(context: Context, photoUri: Uri?): Int {
        /* it's on the external media. */
        val cursor: Cursor? = context.contentResolver.query(
            photoUri!!,
            arrayOf(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION),
            null,
            null,
            null
        )

        if (cursor == null){
            cursor?.close()
            return -1
        }

        if (cursor.count != 1) {
            cursor.close()
            return -1
        }
        cursor.moveToFirst()
        val orientation = cursor.getInt(0)
        cursor.close()
        return orientation
    }
```

And here is how I use this

```
        val imageFile = if (!needsResizing) {
            createTempFileFromUri(uri = imageFileUri)
        } else {

            val bt = getCorrectlyOrientedImage(imageFileUri)

            val tempFile = File(context.filesDir.toString() + "tempfile")

            bt!!.compress(
                Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,
                100,
                tempFile.outputStream()
            )

            bt.recycle()
            tempFile //set the imageFile to be equal to tempFile
        }
```

If the image doesn't need resizing it's all good, if it's too large then I need to resize it and write it to a file.

This is why I need the file

```
   val reqFile: RequestBody =
                imageFile.asRequestBody("multipart/form-data".toMediaTypeOrNull())
            val image = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("image", imageFile.name, reqFile)
```

Comment: No. Bitmap.compress() does not rotate anything. But BitmapFactory.loadFrom... does not take in account the orientation information in the source file.

Comment: You should take orientation information from the exif header in the file. There are not much devices/camera apps where orientation information is stored in media store.

Comment: Thank you @blackapps for pointing me in the right direction. Managed to solve it finally